# Simplifying Jquery

Tags: image, jquery, loader, preloader

I'm trying my hardest to simplifying the code below....

You'll see there's 3 different images that triggers to the large image, I guess you can call it as click-able slideshow. I would like to add a preloaded image when the user clicks the image.

Also, keep in mind there's a 2,3,4 batch just like this. I would like make this clean and light as possible.

**Any thoughts?**

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
#loader.loading {
    background: url(http://jqueryfordesigners.com/images/spinner.gif) no-repeat center center;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#ml-games-collection .game1-btn").click(function () {
        $("#ml-display li.game").removeClass("hide").css("display", "none");
        $("#ml-display .game1").show();
    });

    $("#ml-display .game1-ss1 img").bind("click", function () {
        $("#ml-display .game1-large-display").attr({
            "alt": "img alt 1 - screenshot 1",
            "src": "image 1"
        });
    });
    $("#ml-display .game1-ss2 img").bind("click", function () {
        $("#ml-display .game1-large-display").attr({
            "alt": "img alt 2 - screenshot 1",
            "src": "image 2"
        });
    });
    $("#ml-display .game1-ss3 img").bind("click", function () {
        $("#ml-display .game1-large-display").attr({
            "alt": "img alt 3 - screenshot 1",
            "src": "image 3"
        });
    });



</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="column span-20 last game" id="ml-display">
  <ul style="padding-bottom:0;" class="game-list  no-list-style">
    <li class="game1 game" style=""> 
     <div id="loader" class="loading">
    <img width="500" height="313" alt="img alt 2 - screenshot 1" src="" class="game1-large-display right">
      <ul class="screen-shots no-list-style">
        <li><a title="" class="game1-ss1 click"><img alt=" Tiny Screen Shot" src=""></a></li>
        <li><a title="" class="game1-ss2 click"><img alt=" Tiny Screen Shot" src=""></a></li>
        <li><a title="" class="game1-ss3 click"><img alt=" Tiny Screen Shot" src=""></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so you want to clean up your jQuery code, that's all?

Comment: yes, as well as add preloader image.

Comment: you should ask that in a separate question, a preloader is a lot different than code cleanup... and definitely worthy of a separate question. Although, asking somebody to write the code for you might not get the best response, it'd be better if you attempted to tackle it and asked questions along he way, or asked for a high-level description of how to go about creating a preloader.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap each image an

```
<a href="url-of-bigger-picture.jpg" title="text to use for alt">
    <img ...>
</a>
```

Then your JS becomes:

```
$("#ml-games-collection .game1-btn").click(function () {
    $("#ml-display li.game").removeClass("hide").css("display", "none");
    $("#ml-display .game1").show();
});

$("#ml-display .game1-ss1 .clickable").bind("click", function (event) {
    var target = $(event.target);

    $("#ml-display .game1-large-display").attr({
        "alt": target.attr("title"),
        "title": target.attr("title"),
        "src": target.attr("href")
    });
});
```